# How to bring up the wallet multi adapter select screen manually in a react app

Tags: react, walletadapter

I've got a unity game that has a 'connect wallet' button within it.  In my react app I am listening for that being clicked, and what I would like to do is then pop up the standard multi wallet connect screen that you get when clicking a WalletMultiButton.  I've tried to find some examples online and failed, and also tried to parse the git repo to understand what the button is doing.. but also failed.

Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
import { useWalletModal } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
```

This gives you access to:

```
const { setVisible } = useWalletModal();
```

… then you can call `setVisible(true)` to show the menu.